# Insert Into Select on table with composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If you have a table with two primary keys:

```
CREATE TABLE [AttributeMap](
[intParentAttributeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[intChildAttributeId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [datCreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
  CONSTRAINT [PK_AttributeMap] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 ( 
   [intParentAttributeId] ASC,
    [intChildAttributeId] ASC
 )
```

If you want to do an insert into/select statement to add data to the table, how can you restrict the data to make sure it doesn't violate both keys?

So if you insert this into the table above:

```
INSERT INTO [AttributeMap] VALUES (1, 1, getdate())
INSERT INTO [AttributeMap] VALUES (1, 2, getdate())
INSERT INTO [AttributeMap] VALUES (1, 3, getdate())
INSERT INTO [AttributeMap] VALUES (2, 1, getdate())
```

How could you run this query without violating the keys?

```
declare table @temp (intParent int, intChild int)
insert into @temp (1, 1)
insert into @temp (1, 2)
insert into @temp (4, 4)
insert into @temp (5, 5)

 insert into AttributeMap (intParentAttributeId, intChildAttributeId, datCreatedDate)
  select intParent, intChild, getDate()
 from @temp
```

So AttributeMap should end up with two new rows, values 4, 4, "date" and 5, 5 "date". Make sense?

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: The table *doesn't* have two primary keys - it has a *single*, composite primary key. You can *only* have one primary key in SQL (although you can have additional keys, they have to be declared as unique key constraints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

> Returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the EXCEPT operand that are not also returned from the right query.

Try this:

```
insert into AttributeMap (intParentAttributeId, intChildAttributeId, datCreatedDate)
Select temp.intParent, temp.intChild, getDate()
FROM 
(select intParent, intChild
from @temp 
EXCEPT 
select intParentAttributeId, intChildAttributeId
from AttributeMap) as temp
```

Comment: I was just about tho post almost the same solution. :) But you beat me to it so I just give you a +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to check manually whether the key already exist and insert only if it does not:

```
 insert into AttributeMap (intParentAttributeId, intChildAttributeId, datCreatedDate)
 select intParent, intChild, getDate()
   from @temp t
  where not exists (select null
                      from AttributeMap
                     where AttributeMap.intParent = t.intParent
                       and AttributeMap.intChild = t.intChild
                   )
```